# JS a div is not showing after page refresh

Tags: javascript

In registration form I have a 2 radio button, when one button is selected a dropdown list appears. But after register fails, the selected radio button remains but the dropdown list is not shown anymore, I want the dropdown list to be shown after register fail. There should be a solution with local storage but I dont know exactly how to write it.

here is the code, what I should add to make it happen?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[type=radio][name=rdUserType]').change(function() {
            if (this.value == '1') {
                $('#cityClient').show();
                $('#cityLawyer').hide();
            }
            else if (this.value == '0') {
                $('#cityClient').hide();
                $('#cityLawyer').show();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Have you read about [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)? It's pretty easy to imlement.

Comment: yeah I do read, and try now but It didnt work.. anyway I keep try then

Comment: Please post what you tried with `localStorage` along with what errors you got when you tried.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution finally, I tried and made it :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=radio][name=rdUserType]').change(function() {


        if (this.value == '1') {
            $('#cityClient').show();
            $('#cityLawyer').hide();
        }
        else if (this.value == '0') {
            $('#cityClient').hide();
            $('#cityLawyer').show();
        }
        localStorage.removeItem("last");
    });
});

function fix(){

    var check = localStorage.getItem("last");
    console.log(check);

    if (check === 'a') {
            $('#cityClient').hide();
            $('#cityLawyer').show();
        }
        else{
            $('#cityClient').show();
            $('#cityLawyer').hide();
        }

}

function save(){
    // rdAttorney is a id of the selected radio
   if (document.getElementById('rdAttorney').checked) {
          localStorage.setItem('last', 'a');
        }
        else{
           localStorage.setItem('last', 'b'); 
        }

}

window.onload = fix();

</script>
```

Comment: Instead of `window.onload = fix();` (which is incorrect and causes `fix` to be executed before `window.onload` because you have `()` after `fix`), just place `fix()` as the first line of code inside your `document.ready()` function.

Comment: Then you didn't follow my instructions properly or you have other issues.

Comment: As I said, `window.onload = fix();` doesn't actually wait until the window is loaded to run `fix` because you've added `()` after `fix`, which indicates that it should run immediately. The correct code would be `window.onload = fix`. And, the whole point of `document.ready` is to have a place to put code that should run as soon as the document is ready, which is essentially what `window.onload` is, so having both is redundant. Just placing `fix()` as the first line of code inside your `document.ready` callback function removes the need for the entire `window.onload` line.

Comment: OK I understood what you mean now, I will try it then.